# How can I group by two rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

In the result of an SQL Select command I have two rows:

```
A |  B
B |  A
```

A|B and B|A means the same to me. I want, that only one of them would be selected in an SQL command.

How can I do that?

I have a select command , I join it self (natural join), like this:

```
SELECT a.coloumn ,b.coloumn 
FROM table a,table b
where .... (not important)
and b.coloumn  IN (
  SELECT coloumn
  FROM table
  where ... (the same like above)
)
and b.coloumn != a.coloumn ;
```

And after that I have multiple coloumns.

Comment: Is it MySQL or Oracle? You tagged both. And can you give more context?

Comment: I would like to get a Standard oracle sql command for this.

Answer (score 7):

You neither told us your column names nor your table name, but assuming you have two columns `A` and `B` in a table named `the_table` then the following will do:

```
select distinct least(a,b), greatest(a,b)
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *group* by them using standard SQL:

```
select (case when a < b then a else b end) as a,
       (case when a < b then b else a end) as b,
       count(*) as cnt
from table t
group by (case when a < b then a else b end),
         (case when a < b then b else a end);
```

Oracle supports the `greatest()` and `least()` functions, but not all databases do.

Comment: I'm curious: which DBMS does not support `greatest` and `least`? I thought they were pretty standard.

Comment: SQL Server, Sybase, Access (if you consider that a database), Teradata, and SQLite come to mind.

Comment: DB2 has these two functions.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is:

```sql
select a, b from the_table
union
select b, a from the_table
```

This would work fine even if there are `NULL` values.